# How to connect to HyperSQL DB from C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, hsqldb

We are searching for an In Memory DB with required features:

> - Client/Server mode
> - Support SQL, stored procedure
> - Can run in "In Memory" mode
> - Light and fast
> - Free
> - Can be connect from C#

HSQLDB meets all of our requirement. But we have trouble with the last option. We cannot find any component to connect from C# to this DB.
Please recommend us a good connectivity component or other DB that can meet all of our requirement.
Thanks.

Comment: How about [C# SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/)?

Comment: SQLite cannot run in Client/Server mode.

Answer (score 0):

A translation of HSQLDB 2.x to C# with some enhancments related to MS platforms exists. The main web site seems to have gone, but the blog is still there:

http://blog.effiproz.com/

Comment: :( I need only client side library.